# Unexpected output with input and print functions in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm trying to jump from line to line but I read somewhere that's it's bad to do goto in python or something like that. So I decided to write the code like this.

```
def event_1():
    dsc_1 = input(print("Will you (1) turn west or (2) turn east? > "))
    if dsc_1 == "1":
        event_2()
    elif dsc_1 == "2":
        event_3()


def event_2():
    print("You have turned west.")


def event_3():
    print("You have turned east.")


event_1()
```

And this returns this:

```
Will you (1) turn west or (2) turn east? >
None
```

Now if I enter 2 after, this happens

```
Will you (1) turn west or (2) turn east? >
None2
You have turned east.
```

So this is what I want to happen, but I want to input to happen after the ">". I also don't understand why the code is returning "None". Like I said before, I'm new to python and coding so if you guys have any suggestions on how to do this better it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: `input(print())` is likely not what you want, have you checked the documentation for `input()` ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `print` statement in the `input` function.

```
def event_1():
    dsc_1 = input("Will you (1) turn west or (2) turn east? > ")
    if dsc_1 == "1":
        event_2()
    elif dsc_1 == "2":
        event_3()


def event_2():
    print("You have turned west.")


def event_3():
    print("You have turned east.")


event_1()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Will you (1) turn west or (2) turn east? > 2
You have turned east.
```

/

```
Will you (1) turn west or (2) turn east? > 1
You have turned west.
```